# Why doesn't the base class constructor set the values?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Here, values of x and y is being tried to set through base class constructor.

But, the code is unable to do so.

```
#include <iostream>

class Point2d {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Point2d() : x(0), y(0) {
    }
    Point2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {
    }
    void Show() {
        std::cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
    }
};

class Vector2d : public Point2d {
public:
    Vector2d():Point2d(){
    }
    Vector2d(double x, double y) : Point2d(x,y) {       
    }
    Vector2d(Vector2d const& vec) : Point2d(vec){
    } 
    void Set(double x, double y) {
        Point2d::Point2d(x, y);
    }
};

int main() {
    Vector2d v;
    v.Set(20, -39);
    v.Show(); // prints '(0,0)' instead of '(20,-39)'
}
```

My target is to reuse base class constructor, and, overloaded assignment operators as much as possible.

Comment: You neither said precisely what happened nor what you expected. That said, you are trying to invoke the constructor outside of object construction, but only create a temporary, anonymous object. There are ways to do what you want involving placement new, but the approach is flawed. Just set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your code won't even compile at

```
void Set(double x, double y)
{
    Point2d::Point2d(x, y);
}
```

A constructor of a base class should be called at the beginning of the member initializer lists of a subclass constructor, not in a member function.

What you need is probably

```
class Point2d {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Point2d() : x(0), y(0) {
    }
    Point2d(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {
    }
    void Show() {
        std::cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")\n";
    }
    Point2d& operator=(Point2d const& rhs)
    {
        this->x = rhs.x;
        this->y = rhs.y;
    }
};

class Vector2d : public Point2d {
public:
    Vector2d():Point2d(){
    }
    Vector2d(double x, double y) : Point2d(x,y) {       
    }
    Vector2d(Vector2d const& vec) : Point2d(vec){
    }

    /* also need to be overloaded in the subclass */
    Vector2d& operator=(Vector2d const& rhs)
    {
        Point2d::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    void Set(double x, double y) {
        *this = Vector2d(x, y);
    }
};

int main() {
    Vector2d v;
    v.Set(20, -39);
    v.Show();
}
```

Comment: It compiles but values are not being set.

Comment: What is the problem with this code:`class Vector2d:publicPoint2d{void Set(double x, double y) { *this = Vector2d(x, y); } void Set(Vector2d const& vec) { *this = Vector2d(vec); }};`

Comment: It is not included in the code in your question. Have you paste some wrong code? I try to compile your code (updated) with `g++` or `g++ -std=c++0x` it indeed gives the error at the `Set` function.

Comment: `1>Rebuild All started: Project: DerivedClassConstructorReuse, Configuration: Debug Win32
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project '...', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>Compiling manifest to resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest..
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\...\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>DerivedClassConstructorReuse - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
=== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ===
`

Comment: @anonymous I see, your question is not about base class construct but assignment operator overloading, is it? See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to construct the base class in the setter function, but the base class will already be constructed when the derived class is constructed. I would just set the x and y values of the base class in the setter.

Comment: What is the problem with this code:`class Vector2d:publicPoint2d{void Set(double x, double y)
 {
  *this = Vector2d(x, y);
 }
 void Set(Vector2d const& vec)
 {
  *this = Vector2d(vec);
 }};`